# Cocoapods 1.4.0 With iOS Testing

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to write Test cases for swift app, I have problem accessing main target classes from test folder

Here is my Pod file

```
target 'ProjectName' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.6'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'TwitterKit'

  target 'ProjectNameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

  target 'ProjectNameUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end
```

My test case is here

```
import XCTest
import Foundation

@testable import ProjectName

class SimpleTests: XCTestCase {

    func test1(){
        var a = Profile();
    }
}
```

`Profile` class is located in main target, I can see this class , but after running I get this error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__T013ProjectName7ProfileCMa", referenced from:
      __T018ProjectNameTests06SimpleC0C5test1yyF in ProjectNameTests.o
  "__T013ProjectName7ProfileCACSS10jsonString_tcfC", referenced from:
      __T018ProjectNameTests06SimpleC0C5test1yyF in ProjectNameTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I remove line `var a = Profile()`, Test is working

Answer (score 0):

You also need to import framework in your test class. For e.g. if you want to use SwiftyJSON feature in your test class.

You need to write -

```
import SwiftyJSON
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this error occur for any classes, for empty classes also

Comment: @testable import ProjectName - is project name is same as your app's target name? it should be target name.